# Window closing in Swing Application Framework

Tags: java, swing, swingx, swing-app-framework

I am using Swing Application Framework JSR(296) for my Swing based Java application.

Similar to AboutBox, I have followed the usage of @Action and added some JDialog classes to my project.

The problem is, when I close the main frame, my application still runs in background.
To overcome this I added following code to the configureWindow() of my main application class:

```
protected void configureWindow(java.awt.Window root) {

    root.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        // write your code here
            Application.getInstance(MyApp.class).exit();
        }
    });
}
```

But with this modification whenever I close the the dialog (including AboutBox), it also closes the main frame.

What should I do to prevent the entire application from exiting and just close the dialog box?

**Update:**
I am using NetBeans IDE 7.01 which allows to create Swing Application Framework project.
It generates a project skeleton as shown below:

```
MyApp 
|--myapp 
|   |--MyApp.java
|   |--MyAppAboutBox.java
|   |--MyAppView.java
|
|--myapp.resources
    |--MyApp.properties
    |--MyAppAboutBox.properties
    |--MyAppView.properties
```

NetBeans IDE allows to add actions from *Window->Properties menu*.

MyApp class extends org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication which is my main class.

`MyAppView extends FrameView` which is my main view.

Implementation classes of `javax.swing.JDialog` are in the `myapp.view` package.

Comment: You may want to look at this: http://www.jroller.com/tackline/entry/closing_dialogs_on_escape and see how he closes the dialog.

Comment: Thanks, here I guess, I have a problem with the implementation of configuerWindow() of org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication

Comment: hmm .. nothing much doable without seeing an sscce (note: the standalone includes no dependency on Netbeans :-) - closing the main should close all related/secondary windows/dialogs by default, nothing to do manually.

Comment: It started with this - the application was still running in background even after closing from X close option (top right corner in windows environment)

Comment: as I said: it shouldn't - you either show an sscce or are on your own ... crystal balls are soooo old school that they were banned here :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [WindowEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowEvent.html) class has a method call [getWindow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowEvent.html#getWindow%28%29), which returns the window that is closing.

Inside your `windowClosing` method you can check: if the window is the main application window, use the code that you currently have. If it is not, just call [Window.dispose()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29)

**Edit**: I didn't notice that you were creating custom dialogs in your application. Maybe you forget to dispose them? You should add code like the one in the auto generated about box:

```
@Action public void closeAboutBox() {
    dispose();
}
```

and call this action whenever the dialog closes. If this is not the problem, a thread dump will probably help you in order to find out which thread is running when you close the main window.

Comment: Hi, this works. My main window/view/frame is an instance of `JFrame`. so for every window close, i am checking whether it's an instance of `JFrame` before calling `Application.getInstance(MyApp.class).exit()`. but then why should I use the SAF? this framework has it's lifecycle which is what i am intrested in. +1

Comment: technically correct (+1), just not following the winds of appframework :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are actually looking for is `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`. Have a look at the  [JavaDoc API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29)...